# ArrayList.contains() method not work

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, contains

I have an `ArrayList` ordineDopoModifica

```
public static ArrayList<Persona> ordineDopoModifica = new ArrayList<Persona>();
```

This is the Persona class:

```
class Persona {

public String nome;
public String prezzo;
public String ingredienti;
public String codp;
public byte[] immagine;}
```

Now I want to say if a int is contained in ordineDopoModifica...

This is what I do now:

```
boolean c=sceltacibo.ordineDopoModifica.contains(chiave);
```

Here's my overridden equals method:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
      return false;
    }

    if (obj instanceof Persona) {
        Persona p = (Persona) obj;
        return codp.equals(p.codp);
    } 

    else return false;

  }
```

But `boolean c=sceltacibo.ordineDopoModifica.contains(chiave);` doesn't work - it always returns false, even though I'm sure `chiave` is in the `ArrayList`.

Comment: Show a complete example of what does not work.

Comment: do you override hashCode() aswell? because you should

Comment: I'm pretty sure `contains` work... Check your `equals`

Comment: what's `chiave`'s type? If it is any other type than `Persona` your `instanceof` will always evaluate to `false`...

Comment: chiave=String, chiave is a temp String. I want to say if chiave is in my array, chiave=codp!

Comment: `codp` isn't even an int, it is a String. Compare it with a String.

Comment: Yes yes, I made a writing mistake, chiave is String value but code don't work!

Comment: @Mikykly See the comments in my answer. You should get the help you need to take you forward with this. Loop through the elements, then **for each** element, check if the strings are equal. If so, return your object.

Comment: @MagnusTengdahl No, I can't solve the problem with a loop through the elements! Why is contains method wrong?

Comment: @Mikykly I clarified my answer, but you won't get more help than this. I suggest you think it through carefully, I'm sure you can figure it out. Your method is not wrong, your usage of it is.

Answer (score 7):

> Now i want to say if a int is contains in my arrayList ordineDopoModifica...

You are checking if `ArrayList<Persona> ordineDopoModifica` contains an `int`. It doesn't, it only contains `Persona` objects, hence it always returns false.

To be more precise, `equals(Object obj)` will fail here:

```
if (obj instanceof Persona) {
    Persona p = (Persona) obj;
    return codp.equals(p.codp);
} else 
    return false;
```

This is because an `Integer` is not an instance of `Persona`.

Comment: Yes, but If i've in my arrayLIst ordineDopoModifica: cod=13 nome=hello   qnt=3, How I can do if I want to see if myArray.contains(cod=13)?

Comment: @Mikykly Iterate through the list, and for each `Persona` instance, do the check you want to do. If you get a hit, return the object.

Comment: @Mikykly and under no circumstances include an `instanceof` check against a numeric type in your `equals` method, you'll certainly create a source of bugs. Just a friendly advice here.